# MySQL Database model

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Please tell me if this database model is correct. In my database I would like to store information about computer sets (computer + monitors + printers). It is possible, that set has two or more monitors and printers.

[image: Database model]

Comment: could you please provide more detail about set and set device relation, and it is needed to define relation between set_device and device itself, in this kind of relation one device with a given id can be belong to many set with different owner, that is not true I think, but for monitor, printer and computer you did well I think

Comment: @SirvanParaste, one set = one owner :)

Comment: and one set = many device ?
one device = many computer,printer,monitor,other?

Comment: One set = one computer, but many printers, many monitors and others

Comment: so the above model is not correct, I will update my answer, if it is useful you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated
based on the detail you've provided , I think you do not need the set_device table, because it will cause problems and you need to handle it in code,

for example : Person with ID p1 has a set with id S1
          And Person with id P2 has a set with id S2
Given a device with id D1, 
in this example in the set_device table you can see such records :

```
> id     device_id   set_id
> 1      D1          S1
> 2      D1          S2
```

which can not be allowed, It could be better remove that table and add the set_id to the device table as a fk.

this way set can has more than one device but each device will limited to one set and one owner as well.

Updated based on new details : one_set = one_computer and many monitor, printer.

In this case it is better to combine device and computer table as a single table.

[image: new diagram]

notice that in this design each set can have many computer !! if you have a one to one relation between computer and set so you can combine both of them as a single table, and then the design will be ok.

hope this will help you.
I will update the answer if you give more details.